# What was the standard size of drywall panels made around 1960?

Tags: drywall

I need to remove an old ceiling and I am told that the older drywall panels did not use to be 4'x 8'.

What size did they use to be ?

Comment: Why does it matter if the old drywall panels were a different size? You will be tearing it off and throwing it away. The spacing between the studs to fasten new drywall is all that matters and even then you could cut to size if you had odd stud spacing—you will be cutting some drywall to size regardless.

Comment: true but I want to know what I can expect if I go in the attic and I cut the nails that hold the pannels, will they fall off ? (I want them to :-)) )   Not sure why a contractor I wanted to hire mentioned that as an impediment to the above way of demolishing a ceiling without cutting it in to pieces and making lots of dust

Comment: I think any way you do it, you should expect a lot of dry wall dust both in demolition and in refinishing. I would just go with whichever way is fastest on demolition and cutting each nail individually could be a real pain since you will first need to make enough room between the nail and the drywall for your sawzall to fit which means you will need to push out the panel slightly. At that point, I say just rip off the drywall and come back to fully pull out any remaining nails with a claw hammer.

Comment: the guy suspects the finish is Artex (possible asbestos) ...so cutting the panel will airborn the dust
I suggested wet the heck out of the finish before cutting it (tedious) or cut the nails and support eacch pannel with the hoist
Cutting can be done with an osculating tool. Dust created at the top above the panel where there is no Artex, will be fine

Comment: I would never cut Sheetrock it will make a much bigger mess than breaking it, the nails are short and with a nice framing hammer 1 swing I used to pull 2-3 nails in a swing sometimes as many as 5 but I did a lot of rip and strips in my youth. Popping the sheets the biggest mess will be insulation and mouse debris from my experience.  I would bet trying to cut will produce more dust than breaking as all the seams have 2 rows of nails and mud covered in tape. A framing hammer has straight claws a framing hammer has curved claws. A framer may have a waffle face or smooth, finish smooth face.

Comment: I guess the first sheet will be the more difficult one. After that you get side access to the nails of the next panel and and you can cut them from that side

Comment: Prudence would dictate you get the material tested to establish whether there's asbestos or not. Having said that, I get that sometimes money outweighs personal safety. Have you considered all your options? Can you, for instance, skin the ceiling with another layer of plasterboard and have the same outcome? If you do end up demoing, I'd encourage you to understand how the professionals do remediation.

Comment: Hazmat suit and 3M 3800 ( https://www.amazon.ca/3M-6800-Facepiece-Reusable-Respirator/dp/B00IROQ1PY) are on the shopping list. Covering the entire room in plastic sheets taped together. Portable dust collector set in the room near the area where I work.  Heavy duty disposal bags

Comment: There is around of fear mongering arund the asbestos topic. Used to charge an arm and a leg for operations that would should be safe with the above. I am also considering wetting the sheets to the point that water drips out of them.
Let's not forget that the drywall does not contain asbestos only the Artex contains SOME asbestos (if proved true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drywall has always been 4x 8 or 12 as long far back as I know it was first used in the 20’s . By the late 40 and 50’s it was the preferred method it las less expensive and easier to install but the size has been similar to plywood 4x8 sheets has been the standard.

Demo of old sheetrock is much easier than today’s screws, knock a hole stick the framing hammer in the hole turn 90 and pull down the sheetrock will break on the nail lines sometimes sections of the nails come out some not but they come out easily except on oak 2x4. In my youth I could strip an entire bedroom in a little over an hour and a half including pulling nails with a framing hammer and wonderbar . It was more work to pick up the peace’s and toss them in the dumpster or if close to the dump in a truck. But you do not cut the nails.

Comment: 1964 built house I had to rip into did have thinner than what's normal today (1/2 or 5/8") in some spots, but you can still buy 1/4 and 3/8 inch thick panels if you need to match that.

Comment: There has been different thickness with 1/2” bringing the most popular thinner sheets usually had a coat of mud to look more like plaster.

Comment: the thickness is my last concern here. I just need to remove the Artex without disturbing it

Comment: The size of drywall / plywood was what drove the size of the first Transit van and its floor - which is why they sold so well: every builder had one...